# ¿Cómo optimizar mis reportes en asp.net c# entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, entity-framework

Actualmente tengo realizado un reporte que lo genera en Excel, lo cual tengo que realizar en un foreach de unas 3 mil iteraciones, varias operaciones aritméticas y condiciones por cada iteración. Localmente el reporte se demora en descargar en 6 minutos, pero cuando está alojado en el servidor, se cae y aparece error 502.
Alguien que me ayude a optimizar ese tipo de reportes, tecnologías que pueda usar o métodos más óptimos por favor.

El error que sale es el siguiente: 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: cuando las operaciones son bastante complicadas, puede serte más rentable crear una vista o una tabla temporal donde tengas los datos que vas a utilizar ya listos

Comment: Jorge. El error que recibes es 502. Imagino es el error que te muestra el front end, después del (posible) 500 que te da el back end. Reportes pesados con Entity Framework son un gran no-no. Si no sabes EXACTAMENTE lo que estás haciendo, terminas con [problemas n+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping), problemas de rendimiento, entre otros. Como @L.Ronquillo dice, déjaselo a la base de datos. Crea un SP, o una vista, y luego consulta datos desde el cliente.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas. Creo que optaré por por un SP